# server side pagination in Angular 5

Tags: angular, pagination, server-side

I need to implement server side pagination that is from api I am getting page number and page limit , I need to display series of button below the table and on click of that button api call will happen with respective button number.Suppose I click button number 2 then i need to display page number 2 data in table.for this I am using angular 5. I tried ngx-pagination but it didn't work for me.My json is like this :

```
[
  {
    "pagecount": [
      {
        "record_count": "69",
        "pagenumber": "0",
        "pagelimit": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "completed": [
      {
        "queueid": "297885",
        "cust_name": "MR DEWESH SHANKER",
        "veh_number": "KA03 MW7878",
        "payment_status": "Paid",
        "queue_total": "7104",
        "rating": "5.0"
      },
      {
        "queueid": "298162",
        "cust_name": "Pratham Motors Stockyard",
        "veh_number": "CH14 0527",
        "payment_status": "Paid",
        "queue_total": "0",
        "rating": "5.0"
      },
      {
        "queueid": "298163",
        "cust_name": "MS PALLAVI R DHOTRAGAVI\t",
        "veh_number": "KA51 MK4228",
        "payment_status": "Paid",
        "queue_total": "2131",
        "rating": "5.0"
      },
      {
        "queueid": "298196",
        "cust_name": "Pratham Motors Stockyard",
        "veh_number": "CH15 9983",
        "payment_status": "Paid",
        "queue_total": "0",
        "rating": "5.0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can i achieve this . Anyone Please ?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table. It has many great features. Not sure this will suite your requirement. But it's worth to have a look :)

Comment: Try using http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

Answer (score 0):

There are number of pagination component available for Angular, some of them which I used are -

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-bootstrap-pagination

You can use

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/paginator

as well depending on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried angular data-table? The configuration is similar to the classic data-table.Looks promising.
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started